# Convert json array column to list of dict in Pyspark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I created a pandas df from a pyspark df in the following way:

```py
pd_df = (
     df
    .withColumn('city_list', F.struct(F.col('n_res'), F.col('city')))
    .groupBy(['user_ip', 'created_month'])
    .agg(
        F.to_json(
            F.sort_array(
                F.collect_list(F.col('city_list')), asc=False
            )
        ).alias('city_list')
    )
).toPandas()
```

However the column `city_list` of my `pd_df` was not converted into a list of dict but into a string.
Here is an example of a column value: `"[{'n_res': 40653, 'city': 00005}, {'n_res': 12498, 'city': 00008}]"`.
A solution could be to call `pd_df.city_list.apply(eval)` But I wouldn't consider it a safe approach.
How can I create a list of dict directly from pyspark?
Thanks.

Comment: Any specific reason you are doing it through pandas_df not through pyspark df

Comment: @SachinTiwari what do you mean?

Comment: why are u converting to pandas df?

Comment: @SachinTiwari because I need it as a pandas dataframe to create a lookup table afterwards